# How to Set two paths in Single Environmental Variable in window 10 (HADOOP_HOME)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have installed HADOOP in window-10, but when i install Apache Spark I have to give Two paths in single variable which is 'HADOOP_HOME' i cannot creat two variables with same name , please guide me how to set two paths in single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously it's not possible, so you're misunderstanding something

If you already have Hadoop, you can download the Spark binaries that aren't bundled with Hadoop themselves. Then it'd use all your existing settings and variables